# Нужно написать программу, на вход которой даются четыре числа a, b, c и d, каждое в своей строке.

Tags: python

Программа должна вывести фрагмент таблицы умножения для всех чисел отрезка [a;b] на все числа отрезка [c;d].
Числа a, b, c и d являются натуральными и не превосходят 10, a≤b, c≤d.
Я начала, а как закончить не знаю.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())
s=''
if a<=b and c<=d:
for i in range (c, d+1):
s=s+[i]
print('\t',i,end='')
for i in range(a, b+1):
print('\n',i,'\t',s[0]*i,'\t',end='')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в задании сказано "a≤b, c≤d", значит так оно и есть, дополнительных проверок вида `if a<=b and c<=d` можно не делать.

```
# ввод данных
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())

# приводим ввод к форме a≤b, c≤d, необязательный шаг (смотри выше)
# a, b = (b, a) if a > b else (a, b)
# c, d = (d, c) if c > d else (c, d)

s = ''
# формируем шапку таблицы
for i in range (c, d + 1):
    s += '\t%s' % i

# заполняем строки таблицы
for i in range(a, b + 1):
    s += '\n%s' % i # выводим текущее число из умножаемого столбеца
    for j in range (c, d + 1):
        s += '\t%s' % (i * j) # выводим результат умножения соответствующих чисел

print(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так

```py
a = range(int(input()), int(input()) + 1)
b = range(int(input()), int(input()) + 1)
print(" ", *b, sep="\t")
for i in a:
    print(i, *(i * j for j in b), sep="\t")
```

Вывод:

```
1
4
5
7
    5   6   7
1   5   6   7
2   10  12  14
3   15  18  21
4   20  24  28
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Ввод данных
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())
#начало Цикла
for g in range (c,d+1):
    print('\t'+str(g),end='')
print(end='\n')
for i in range (a,b+1):
    print(str(i)+'\t',end='')
    for j in range (c,d+1):
        print(str(i * j),end='\t')# выводим результат умножения соответствующих чисел в таблицу
    print(end='\n')
```

Comment: Чем ваш ответ принципиально отличается от уже существующего?

Answer (score 1):

```
a, b, c, d = int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input())

for g in range(c, d + 1):
    print('\t', g, end = '')
for h in range(a, b + 1):
    print('\n', h, end = '')
    for j in range(c, d + 1):
        print('\t', h * j, end = '')
    print(end = '')
```

Вывод:

```
1
4
5
7
     5   6   7
 1   5   6   7
 2   10  12  14
 3   15  18  21
 4   20  24  28
```